# group generated by union of positive reals and complex numbers with modulus one

Tags: group-theory

Starting from the group $(\mathbb{C}_0, \cdot)$, we have subgroups $W = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|=1\}$ and $\mathbb{R}_0^+$ (the strictly positive reals). My question is what the group, generated by $W \cup \mathbb{R}_0^+$, should be.

My intuition tells me $<W \cup \mathbb{R}_0^+> = \mathbb{C}_0$, as $W$ can be represented by a circle with radius 1 in the complex plane and with $\mathbb{R}_0^+$, the radius could be altered, but I'm very unsure of the correctness of my idea.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, given $z\in\mathbb{C_0}$, we can write $z=\frac{z}{|z|}|z|$ where $\frac{z}{|z|}\in W$ and $|z|\in\mathbb{R_0^+}$.